# Laravel import node module

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with implementing node modules with my Laravel app.
In my html file I have like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/gaxon-icon/style.css">
```

And when I look at source code and open this link it's giving 404 error. How to implement this link in my app?

Comment: Laravel comes with a boilerplate `app.scss` any module css should be imported there. You should never have to directly reference anything from `node_modules`

Answer (score 4):

`node_modules` is not accessible from the web server. In fact the only entrypoint for a Laravel app is `public/index.php` and it's not possible to go up one directory.

You should import your assets in your `app.scss` , something like this should work

```
import '~flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.min'
```

Remember to compile your assets after this

```
npm run development (or npm run production when you deploy to your server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the package.

```
npm install lipis/flag-icon-css --save
```

This dependency entry should now be in your package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "flag-icon-css": "github:lipis/flag-icon-css",
```

In /resources/sass/app.scss add:

```
@import '~flag-icon-css/sass/flag-icon';
```

Build your webpack.mix.js configuration.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Compile your assets.

```
npm run prod
```

The SVGs will now be placed into /public/images/vendor/ folder.

Finally, reference your generated CSS file in your Blade template/layout.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```